# Linear Layout space and weight sum

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, screen-size, android-layout-weight

I am new to android , I am trying to make a small calculator as a proof of concept. The problem I am facing is; I always get empty space in the bottom no matter what I am trying to do... Setting my button to fill_parent , changing layout weights. I am stuck, I would like to get some help to figure it out. Maybe there is something that I am missing

this is my layout :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#635c59">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#635c59"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:textSize="31dip"
            android:text="3456+8388388"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MC"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mr"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MR"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ms"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MS"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mplus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="M+"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mminus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#8000ff"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="M-"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_del"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="<--"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ce"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="CE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_c"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_negate"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#0099ce"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="+/-"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sqrt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#8000ff"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="Sqrt"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the code above I took out some part, because it is repetitive what changes is button ids and the color.

as you can see , there is an empty space which I want my buttons to fill the hall linear layout.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

`layout_weight` works well when you set `layout_width` or `layout_height`to `0dp`. In your case, change it to the following:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your upper LinearLayout (the one with "#635c59" as background) to expand, then you could do the following with it:

- remove the layout_weight
- replace the heigt with fill parent
- replace the layout_weight of the lower LinearLayout (the one directly below the FrameLayout) with android:layout_gravity="end"

This will place the lower layout at the bottom and extend the upper one to the rest of the space therefore whowing a grey background.

If you want the buttons to expand hereby filling the whole lower part, then the heigt of the ListViews holding the buttons could be replaced by android:layout_weight="1". Setting the height of the buttons to fill_parent will result in them filling the bottom of your View.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way hope this help you 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#635c59">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#635c59"
            android:textSize="31dip"
            android:text="3456+8388388"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_mc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="MC"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_mr"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="MR"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_ms"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="MS"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_mplus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="M+"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_mminus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8000ff"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="M-"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_del"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="<--"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_ce"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="CE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_c"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="C"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_negate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#0099ce"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_sqrt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#8000ff"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:text="Sqrt"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="28dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone thank you all for your help i was able to solve the problem using a bit of each answer, my Calculator app like any other calculator has a a number keyboard and a display screen , i wanted the display screen to take 1/4 of the space and the keypad the remaining i.e 3/4 of the space , so i created two linear layouts with width set to fill_parent and the height to 0dip , the linear layout with the textView is set the weight to 1 and the keypad linear layout with a weight of 3. inside the keypad layout i created five other linear layouts each for each row and populated each with my buttons giving them a width=fill_parent and a height=fill_parent and weight=1 my buttons occupied the hall space

This is the full code in case anyone wants to check it :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#666666">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:layout_margin="0dip"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:textSize="31dip"
            android:text="3456+8388388"
            android:textColor="#fe2701"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MC"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mr"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MR"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ms"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="MS"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mplus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="M+"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mminus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="M-"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_del"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="<--"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ce"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="CE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_c"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_negate"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="+/-"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sqrt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="Sqrt"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_seven"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_eight"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_nine"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_devide"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_percent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="%"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_four"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_five"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_six"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_inverse"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="1/X"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_one"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_two"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_three"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mimus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_equal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="="
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_zero"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_decimal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="."
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_plus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_mimus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#666666"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ln"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#363636"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:text="Ln"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28dip"
                    android:textColor="#fe2701"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is a screen-shot: at this link (i don't have enough reputation to upload an image) https://www.dropbox.com/s/gztg5b7ih1f2z6z/layout.png